# How to convert diamond grid to row-column coordinates with mouse position in pixel

Tags: geometry

I'm sorry if my question doesn't make any sense

I would like to retrieve the row and column of a diamond based on my mouse position in pixels

Top,right,bottom,left position of the "red" diamond are (500,700) (550,720) (500,740) (450,720) 
Center is (500,700)
The width of each diamond is 50.

Based on these information, how can I determine the row and column of the "blue" diamond who is at position(587,767)

Visually, it's row : 0 and col : 2

And same thing for yellow diamond(663,694)

Visually, it's row : 2 and col : 1

Thanks for your help

EDIT :

$
x_{origin} = 450
$

$
y_{origin} = 720
$

$
row = ((1/100)*(x_{mouse}−x_{origin}) - (1/40)*(y_{mouse}-y_{origin}))
$

$
column = ((1/100)*(x_{mouse}−x_{origin}) + (1/40)*(y_{mouse}-y_{origin}))
$

Issue : When my mouse cursor is placed to the left side
column is 0 and on the right side it's above 1 which is correct

Do I need to take something else into account ? I would like to calculate the correct coordinate as long as I'm inside the diamond

[IMAGE : Mouse placed on the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7861.png)

Mouse Position [607,690] - Row : 2.32 Col : 0.82

[IMAGE : Mouse placed on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCnVW.png)

Mouse Position [658,693] - Row : 2.75 Col : 1.40

It gets worse the further I am from the origin

EDIT 2 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668256/convert-grid-coordinates-to-world-and-back

This person encountered the same issue and his solution is :

> And there I go finding my problem: While running my unit tests, I had
>   flipped one of the axis, but forgot the other one while experimenting,
>   so the tests reported as failed, while visually I was getting
>   incorrect values because of the incorrect pivot point of my sprites.
>   After setting the pivot to the bottom corner, everything worked
>   correctly and my tests were correct all along.

By pivot point, does he mean the origin ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some tools from linear algebra: If $x_{mouse}$ is the two-dimensional vector of your mouse, let $x=x_{mouse}-x_{origin}$ be the pixel position relative to the edge at the left side. We can construct a basis of the plane with the vectors $(50,-20)$ and $(50,20)$, as you can easily see, the integer linear combinations of those are the corner points of the grid. To find the expansion of $x$ by those vectors, you need to do the following:

1) Find the dual basis $f_1$,$f_2$ of this basis. This can be done by writing both basis vectors as columns into a matrix and inverting this matrix, the new collumns are the dual basis vectors.

2) Apply these dual basis vectors to $x$ (using matrix multiplication with $x$ as column vector, $f_1$ and $f_2$ as row vectors) to get numbers $a=f_1(x)$, $b=f_2(x)$

3) Form the least integers below these two real numbers. These are exactly the row and the column that your mouse is at

I hope I made everything clear enough for you to follow, I imagine that if you aren't already familiar with dual spaces this will look a bit like magic, but trust me, it works. If you have any questions about it, feel free to ask. Greetings,

Markus Zetto

Comment: Thanks for your help I've never heard about dual basis before, i'm not sure I understand  2) could you check my edit above ?

Comment: In the inverse matrix, there shouldn't be any $x$, but the numbers are correct. The solution is almost right, if we let $x=x_1+x_2$, it should be (if I am not mistaken)
$$ a = (1/100)x_1 - (1/40)x_2$$
$$b = (1/100)x_1 + (1/40)x_2 $$

Comment: Oh ok then for the blue dot (587,767) /////
a = (1/100)*587 - (1/40)*767  = -13 /////
b = (1/100)*587 + (1/40)*767 = 25.045 //// did I do something wrong ? Row is -13 and col 25

Comment: Nevermind, I'm very stupid ! I had to substract by the origin, thanks for your help

Comment: I feel so stupid it's insane, how I can do the reverse now ? From coordinates to pixel and in the center of the diamond

Comment: The reverse is actually much easier: If you want to find $x$ given $a$ and $b$, just add $0.5$ to both of them first so that you will land in the center in the end, not at the border, than multiply with the basis vectors and add them together, like this:
$$ x = (a+0.5)\cdot v_1 + (b+0.5)\cdot v_2 $$
Where $v_{1,2}$ are the basis vectors we picked in the beginning. Finally, you will need to add the origin again, then you are done. As you can see, aspects of linear algebra which seem very abstract in the beginning (basis, inverse transformations, dual spaces) can be very helpful sometimes!

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm encountering an issue with pixel to coordinates conversion, I end up with two differents value inside a diamond. Could you please check my new edit ? –

Comment: I found the issue, nevermind ! The width and height of the diamond were not accurate... stupid me

Answer (score 0):

If the mouse position is $(x,y)$ the first row is when $1250 \lt \frac 52y-x\lt 1350$ and each row increases $\frac 52y-x$ by $100$.

The row number is then $\left\lfloor \frac 1{100}\left(\frac 52 y -x-1250\right) \right\rfloor$.

The first column is when $2250 \lt \frac 52y+x \lt 2350$, so the column number is $\left\lfloor \frac 1{100}\left(\frac 52 y +x-2250\right) \right\rfloor$